# update model based on global variable value django middleware

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

```
is_paid_member=False #Global variable
```

Function:

```
  global is_paid_member
if is_paid_member == True:
    with transaction.atomic():
        client = ClientProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        client.subscription = "Member"
        client.save(update_fields=['subscription'])
```

I want to update the model based on the value of global variable.This function has to update the model if payment is made.Where do i put this function in order to update the model field?

Im changing is_paid_member to True in the transaction success function

```
@csrf_exempt
def payment_success_member(request):
data = {}
global is_paid_member
is_paid_member=True

user=request.user

return render(request, 'payu_success.html',data)
```

This is payment function:

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def MemberPay(request):
data = {}
global is_paid_member

if is_paid_member == True:
    with transaction.atomic():
        client = ClientProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        client.subscription = "Member"
        client.save(update_fields=['subscription'])
txnid = get_transaction_id()
hash_ = generate_hash_member(request, txnid)
hash_string = get_hash_string_member(request, txnid)
# use constants file to store constant values.
# use test URL for testing
data["action"] = constants.PAYMENT_URL_TEST
amounts = Amount.objects.filter(subscription="Member")

data["amount"] =amounts[0].amount
data["productinfo"] = constants.PAID_FEE_PRODUCT_INFO
data["key"] = config.KEY
data["txnid"] = txnid
data["hash"] = hash_
data["hash_string"] = hash_string
data["firstname"] = request.user.username
data["email"] = request.user.email
data["subscription"] = "Free"

if (request.user.is_client == True):
    data["phone"] = request.user.client_profile.mobile_number
else:
    data["phone"] = request.user.trainer_profile.mobile_number
data["service_provider"] = constants.SERVICE_PROVIDER
data["furl"] = 
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("student:payment_failure_member"))
data["surl"] = 
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("student:payment_success_member"))
if request.user.client_profile.subscription=="Fellow":
    data["subscription"]="Fellow"
if request.user.client_profile.subscription=="Member":
    data["subscription"]="Member"
global is_paid_member
print("PAID: ",is_paid_member)
print(data["subscription"])

if is_paid_member==True:
    with transaction.atomic():
     client= ClientProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
     client.subscription="Member"
     client.save(update_fields=['subscription'])

return render(request, "payu_payment_member.html", data)
```

Comment: You absolutely definitely should not be using a global variable for this. It will apply to all requests handled by that process.

Comment: Please do not use global variables. Global state is - in software engineering in general - considered to be a huge *antipattern* - furthermore it looks like you have several `Client`s, each with their own `is_paid_member`. By setting a global variable, all clients are paying/not paying.

Comment: what is the solution for this.How can i implement this? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @DanielRoseman What is the solution then? How can i implement this?

Comment: I want to update field in the model based on if the user has paid or not. Cannot update in payment_success function. its anonymous user@WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Boolean field` in you model.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
   ....
   ....
   is_paid_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   ....
```

Now, in your callback function `payment_success_member()` get the payment model object using txn_id and update the `is_paid_member` field  :

```
def payment_success_member(request):
    .....
    txn_id = request.data['txn_id']
    payment_obj = Payment.object.get(txn_id=txn_id)
    payment_obj.is_paid_member =True
    payment_obj.save()
    .....
```